# How can out-of-context Java methods be analysed?

Tags: java, static-analysis

I'm trying to do the following: for a given Java method I want to see whether or not this method can be used in certain context and be correct there, i.e. whether there exist certain definitions of classes, fields, methods, etc whose presence make this method correct. For example, the method

```
int m() {
    A a = new A();
    return a.value() + 1;
}
```

is correct when, for example, the class `A` is defined, this class has a public method called `value` and the method returns `int`. On the other hand, for

```
int m() {
    A a1 = new A();
    int n = a1.value();
    A a2 = new A();
    String s = a2.value();
    return s.length() + n;
}
```

there is no context in which the method can be correct. I know that this question can turn out to be a little bit too broad (and kind of theoretical one) but, in general, how can I approach this kind of problem? For one, I know that there should be some kind of type-checking and control-flow analysis. I'm not sure, though, if this is all that has to be done.

Comment: will need to use a class loader too and the classpath that the app under test would have to see if referenced classes are available. And from there reflection to check on method signatures.

Comment: Type system will help, I think. Your second piece of code is wrong because A.value() can't be both int and String. That's exactly what type systems can check

Comment: probably that kind of error makes the method not compile.. how do you want to see if a java is correct without compile it?

Comment: @X-Pippes Maybe to use an algorithm which uses logic similar to the compiler's one but with the difference that when it encounters undefined type it assumes that this type is defined somewhere and only when it finds a contradiction it reports that completion is impossible. However, I have no idea how this can be implemented (if this idea is correct ofc)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why your problem cannot be solved by running the compiler? Thanks